# PHP LDAP Connection to Authenticate against Active Directory from External Server

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I have an external web server trying to authenticate against Active Directory on an internal server via LDAP. I am able to connect and authenticate locally, though using the same code (switching out host and port) am not able to authenticate externally. We have other services that are able to connect and authenticate such as Attask (http://www.attask.com/).

The external server is currently a Linux (gs) on Media Temple running PHP 5.3.15 with LDAP support enabled.

The internal server is currently a Windows Server 2008 box with LDAP and Active Directory.

The code below is the current PHP I am using that was able to connect locally, but having problems on the external server. It basically uses the PHP LDAP connection string and tries to bind. If it fails, it tries to bind anonymously. Both of which aren't working externally and returns the error: Can't contact LDAP server.

```
<?php
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$ldapconfig['host'] = '00.000.000.000';
$ldapconfig['port'] = '636';
$ldapconfig['basedn'] = 'dc=client,dc=eqc,dc=local';

$ds=ldap_connect($ldapconfig['host'], $ldapconfig['port']);

ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, 10);

$dn="".$username."";

if ($bind=ldap_bind($ds, $dn, $password)) {
  echo("Login correct");
} else {

  echo("Unable to bind to server.</br>");

  echo("msg:'".ldap_error($ds)."'</br>".ldap_errno($ds)."");

  if ($bind=ldap_bind($ds)) {

    $filter = "(cn=*)";

    if (!($search=@ldap_search($ds, $ldapconfig['basedn'], $filter))) {
      echo("Unable to search ldap server<br>");
      echo("msg:'".ldap_error($ds)."'</br>");
    } else {
      $number_returned = ldap_count_entries($ds,$search);
      $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $search);
      echo "The number of entries returned is ". $number_returned."<p>";
      for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
        var_dump($info[$i]);
      }
    }
  } else {
    echo("Unable to bind anonymously<br>");
    echo("msg:".ldap_error($ds)."<br>");
  }
}
?>
```

A few notes:

- The external LDAP server is using LDAPS so the suggested host is ldaps://00.000.000.000 on port 636
- I've tried binding with 'username' as well as 'username@00.000.000.000' already
- There is a firewall, however, the external server can successfully ping the internal LDAP server so there is connection taking place on that level.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If there are server settings or things of that nature, would love to know. Also, I've checked out ADFS though could not find a simple script to setup to test without spending a lot time to no end if it didn't work.

Comment: Have you had the firewall rules checked? Pinging (ICMP) has no real relation to LDAP connectivity (in particular, the firewall may have allowed certain connections, but not necessarily incoming connections from your external server over port 636).

Comment: Consider using a known good client, ldapsearch, to verify that the client can connect to the server. Run ldapsearch on the same host where the specified code executes and use the same parameters. See also [Using ldapsearch](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When connecting to AD using LDAPS from a Linux box, I've always had to add the line

```
TLS_REQCERT never
```

in /etc/ldap.conf or equivalent (might require an apache restart - not sure). You can also try the format "ldaps://server.domain.tld:636" for the host, though I don't think that's the issue.

I found some decent documentation at http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Active_Directory_Authentication_using_LDAP, though it appears to be down at the moment. Google's cached version: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Active_Directory_Authentication_using_LDAP

Comment: Thanks for answering, dearlbry. The external Linux server I'm using is on grid-service which doesn't allow access to the ldap.conf file. I've read through the link you suggested and am setting up a dedicated box to try the TLS_REQCERT never. I'll let you know if that works. :)

Comment: That was it, got it working with also adding the cn to the basedn. Thanks so much dearlbry!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if it is an SSL certificate error? Are you using a self signed cert or an official one?

"If you're using SSL (e.g. ldaps) and ldap_bind is throwing 'Unable to bind to server:' errors, check that the hostname used in the ldap_connect matches the 'CN' in the SSL certificate on the LDAP server"  [Source](http://php.net/manual/de/function.ldap-bind.php)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The SSL Cert on the internal server is official and working properly, thus the connection and authentication currently working with Attask as mentioned above. I'm not even sure what distinguishes LDAPS vs. LDAP besides the port and possibly adding LDAPS:// in front of the host IP.